# How to toggle between marker images/colors in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I already have it set up working to change the color of the marker via color replace (I use [Font Awesome markers](https://github.com/nathan-muir/fontawesome-markers))

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        var symbol = this.getIcon();
        symbol.fillColor = 'black';
        this.setIcon(symbol);
    }
})(marker, i));
```

But how do I change it back (toggle)?

I tried it with `if` / `else if` closures, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple if/else-condition works for me:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
    var symbol = this.getIcon();
    symbol.fillColor = (symbol.fillColor==='black')
                          ? 'red'//initial fillColor
                          : 'black';
    this.setIcon(symbol);
});
```